# The appropriate match ratio between case and controls: the obsession with 1:5

Tags: matching, epidemiology, methodology, case-control-study

My intention with this question is to collect relevant references or literature for a recurrent methodological approach commonly applied in health research.

**The main question is**: what is the appropriate ratio between case and controls?

Within my research field (primarily neurosurgery), it seems that almost every paper I've read exclusively match one case with five controls; however, I've never seen a reference to literature that actually investigated or argued this ratio.

Hence, I am seeking methodic literautre - preferable published papers, but not necessarily - that actively discuss or investigate the appropriate matching ratio between case and controls.

The main question yields **a subsequent question**: should researchers apply different case:control-ratios to different study designs? Eg., do a RCT require similar ratios compared to the methodic requirements of an epidemiological study, that match cases to the controls in the general population (through Health Registries)?

Open Discussion is encouraged.